# Optimal synchronization tool

Tags: server, file-manager

Mostly I edit the files on my local server and then upload them to the remote server, but for small changes or for things that can only be tested on the remote computer, I'll edit the remote file directly (using Dreamweaver and a web-dav software called web-drive).

Problem is, after a while I'll wanna edit the file again, and due to a very bad memory and organization, I have to manually check the date of both the remote and local file, in order to select the latest version. Otherwise, the change I have made will be undone as soon as I synchronize the file.

Is there a synchronization tool that automatically compares dates of similar files on the local and remote servers, and then imports/exports the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options in this space. As @Angio points out [Subversion (SVN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) and one of its [popular clients like Tortoise or Smart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients) offers a great solution, but it's not simple to set up and from what you describe it might be using a sledgehammer to crack a walnut.

I've listed the main options below:-

> **FTP Sync Tools**

Simple FTP/SFTP/FTPS tools which sync.

- [TW SiteSync](http://www.tswsitesync.com/) ($59.99 or 30 day demo) is an FTP client which
  performs a programmatic differential synchronization.
- [BestSync](http://www.risefly.com/) and [FTPSync](http://ftpsynch.com/) are free tools which offer similar functionality to SiteSync.
- [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/howto_synchronize_files_with_webserver)

> **Source Control Tools (all supported by sourceforge)**

Source Control tools offer advanced features including rollback, backup, diff and the like

- Subversion (as mentioned above)
- [Git](http://git-scm.com/)
- [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)
- [Bazzar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/)
- [CVS](http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/)

> **Straight file syncronisation**

Tools which syncronise a directory (or group of directories) between your local computer and the webserver/other pc/etc.

- [RSync](http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/rsync-synchronize-web-server-and-your-local-computer.html) see the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) for information about windows versions
- [ViceVersa](http://www.tgrmn.com/web/file_synchronization.htm)

Comment: RSync is great on Linux for syncing and backing up files and folders. SVN does have a learning curve but you can roll back to previous versions of files if you make a mistake.

Comment: @Anagio rSync runs on windows too, and I do point out that SVN and similar programs offer rollback. In this situation, though, those features might be too much work/hassle etc.

Comment: Wasn't aware rsync ran on windows. I agree though about SVN being too much work for updating files here and there through dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0):

I often use WinMerge to compare files http://winmerge.org/ it will highlight differences in two files which are opened side by side.

Your other option is to learn to use SVN which will manage your file changes and keep your files up to date. You can work in a branch make changes to code and merge it to your trunk.